# What exactly is "Force"? (Mainly the 4 fundamental force)

Tags: forces, standard-model, interactions

First of all, please forgive me for my messy and inexperienced question.
I'm not yet familiar with higher-level physics but the question I'm posting here has bugged me for quite some time.

Why do we require a particle of exchange to understand strong nuclear force?

Like, For in electromagnetic force, we introduced the analogy of positive and negative charges...
In gravitational, we use the bending of the space-time fabric to explain the gravitational force.

Now,  for the strong nuclear force, we express the exchange of mesons between nucleons.

So, why do we do that? - introduce some third concept to explain the general analogy of 'force'.
Can't we explain all the forces with a single third-party concept like just space-time fabric bending to explain all forces, be they real or pseudo or fundamental forces?

Or all forces having a particle of exchange between them...

Thank you for bearing with my silly question and kindly guide me and suggest me some books so that I can understand the concept in a better way. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questions you are asking are confused , and need a course in quantum mechanics to be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Force" is a model that goes well with Newton mechanics. Relativity makes it somewhat shaky.

When we apply it for electromagnetic phenomena, it works... over a tiny island of low-energy events and if one carefully avoids some sneaky traps.

The strong force and the weak force are called forces only because of mental inertia, the word "force" is used only as a synonym for "interaction" and has almost nothing to do with Newtonian forces. One needs a full-blown quantum models in order to understand these things. No "force"-like simplifications are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The "four fundamental forces" aren't really fundamental at all. Fundamentally, force is what a force gauge measures. Physics isn't founded on mathematical abstraction, it's founded on experiment and observation. Certain subatomic interactions are, in a sense, force-like, and gravitation is force-like in a different way. On the other hand, the Pauli force that keeps you from falling through the floor is unaccountably not included.